# Adding Resources into an Existing Maven Project

Tags: java, maven

I have the code written that should work if I could get it to run. [This](https://github.com/amzn/alexa-avs-raspberry-pi/issues/109) is the issue that I'm having. I basically don't know how to add my resources to the existing maven project and put all the dependencies in correctly by modifying the pom.xml file, what my file structure should look like, etc. My main question is how do I fix the classpath issue in maven?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add the resource to your dependency list in your maven pom:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.pi4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>pi4j-core</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
</dependency>
```

I assume this is the jar you are trying to use? If not, here is a whole list of com.pi4j group's jar files in the maven repo:

http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.pi4j

Change the version numbers as needed.

Comment: This is a good answer and IS part (but only part) of what I was missing. I now get an issue when trying mvn exec:exec saying that I need to be in root and sudo mvn exec:exec does not work. Any ideas?

Comment: You probably need to give the absolute path to the maven executable when running sudo. Try running whereis mvn, then use that output as the absolute path for your sudo command (sudo /path/to/mvn exec:exec). Additionally, you can try instead: sudo env "PATH=$PATH" mvn exec:exec